# Is it possible to DEFLATE a .woff2 file in .htaccess in nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mime-types, mod-deflate, woff2

I have the following in my global **.htaccess** file on my **nginx** server:

```
# COMPRESS FILES

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  
  [...]

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff2
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2

  [...]

</IfModule>
```

I understand there was some controversy a while back over what `MIME` Type should represent `.woff2` files, but I was hoping that *one* of these lines:

- `application/font-woff2`
- `font/woff2`

would work.

Apparently, neither does.

---

**Further Info:**

- I don't have any deeper `.htaccess` files overriding the global `.htaccess` file
- My server version is **nginx/1.21.6** (on this basis, I've never really understood how `.htaccess` directives work at all, but I use a good handful of modules and all the directives work)

---

**Question:**

Am I using the wrong `MIME` Type?

Or is the issue likely to be `nginx` related?

*(Or something else which hasn't crossed my mind yet...) ?*

Comment: This is probably a rather pointless attempt to begin with - the woff2 format _is_ already compressed, see https://web.dev/reduce-webfont-size/#web-fonts-and-compression And compressing already compressed data a second time, usually gives very very little benefit.

Comment: @CBroe - Ah... that's good to learn. Thanks. I did *not* know that `woff2` has **brotli** compression already built-in. In which case I agree with you - likely no need to attempt to `DEFLATE` at all. If you want to add that as an answer below, I will accept. Thank you.

Comment: It is also pointless to attempt to configure Nginx using an `.htaccess` file. The file is only understood by and intended for an Apache web server.

Comment: @RichardSmith - You'd certainly be forgiven for thinking so. I've always worked on the basis that this would be the case. So I have, to date, no explanation as to why all the `.htaccess` directives work on the `nginx` server. I can only guess that there must be some `nginx` module which can and does interpret `.htaccess` files - but if there is, I have yet to find it.

Comment: Compression should be configured in your nginx.conf file. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: I have no `nginx.conf` file. It's probably easier if we just pretend I have an Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you shall modify nginx.conf file to add the required compression.

.htaccess file will not work in NGINX

To have better coverage on compression and performance over NGINX, you may use pagespeed module

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module

Example code block for nginx.conf file

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
zip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;

gzip_types
  font/eot
  font/otf
  font/ttf
  image/svg+xml
  text/css
  text/javascript
  text/plain
  text/xml;
```

Comment: Thank you, @Irshad. It's probably easier (for the purposes of this question) if we just pretend that I have an Apache server.